# Скрипт не выполняет код в main()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проблема в том что скрипт не выводит текст который размещен в инструкции **main()**.

```
import os
from os.path import splitext
import fnmatch

print ('Производиться поиск ключевого \nслова во всех файлах заданой директории \nкроме расширений *.exe, *.zip, *.xls(x), \n*.dot(x), *.apk, *.dll, *.doc(x), *.ppt(x).')
print ('\n----------------------------------\n')

def main():
    path = input('Директория: ')
    while not os.path.isdir(path): #проверка пути
        print('Такого каталога нет')
        path = input('Директория: ')
        return

    pattern = input('Искаемое слово: ')

    keyword = get_keyword(pattern)

    EXCL_EXTS = ('.exe', '.zip', '.xls(x)', '.dot(x)', '.apk', '.dll', '.doc(x)', '.ppt(x')

    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file_name in files:
            fn, fext = splitext(file_name)
            if fext not in EXCL_EXTS:
                continue
            inp = open(os.path.join(path, file_name), 'r')
            for line in inp:
                if pattern in line:
                    print(os.path.join(path, file_name))
```

Почему скрипт не выводит 'Директория: '?

Comment: Потому что функция main() у вас никак не вызывается.

Comment: А это что, весь код? Он вот так вот резко обрывается?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: причина для закрытия не верна 1. проблема воспроизводится (достаточно код в вопросе запустить) 2. И я не думаю, что  проблема в простой опечатке. В таких языках как C, Java, Go `main()` явно не вызывается, поэтому это ожидаемая ошибка для людей, знакомых с подобными языками, но новичками в Питоне.

Answer (score 2):

`main()` не является специальной функцией в Питоне. Её следует вызвать явно как любую другую функцию:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#file: your_program.py
import sys
print('display during import')

def main():
    print('hello{} world'.format(' verbose' * ('--verbose' in sys.argv)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`if __name__ == "__main__"` используется, чтобы `main()` вызывалась только при исполнении скрипта и чтобы `main()` *не* вызывалась во время импортирования как модуль в какой-то другой Питон программе. Например, вот скрипт, который всегда добавляет `--verbose` параметр перед тем как вызывать `main()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#file: your-program-verbose.py
import sys
import your_program # 'display during import' is printed here

sys.argv.append('--verbose') # make it verbose
your_program.main()          # 'hello verbose world' is printed here
```

`python your-program-verbose.py` печатает `display during import` и `hello verbose world`. Тот же результат должен быть, если запустить `python your_program.py --verbose`.
Если запустить `python -c 'import your_program'`, то только `display during import` должно напечататься.

Чтобы пошагово посмотреть что происходит, можно запустить отладчик, например:

```
$ python -mpdb your_program.py
```